# How can I verify the full url that my Rspec/Capybara test visits?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I am trying to use Rspec/Capybara to test a non-ruby app.  The app runs in a docker container and the rspec process runs in another container.  When I shell into the rspec container, I can curl the app container without a problem.  But when I run rspec to test the app, it can't connect.  The first thing I want to do is verify the url that Rspec is calling, i.e. what it 'visits'. How can I verify this url

```
RSpec.feature 'user visits homepage', type: :feature do
  scenario 'default' do
    visit '/' # <- how can i print out what url this points to?
    expect(page).to have_content('test content')
  end
end
```

Comment: Since this is essentially a Cross Site request based on your design and you confirmed curl works why not use a HTTP library for your testing?

Answer (score 1):

```
RSpec.feature 'user visits homepage', type: :feature do
 scenario 'default' do
  visit '/'
  puts current_url
  expect(page).to have_content('test content')
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using one of the JS capable Capybara drivers (selenium, poltergeist, capybara-webkit), and have set `Capybara.run_server = false` since you're testing an app launched elsewhere,  `visit '/'` would attempt to connect to "#{Capybara.app_host}/", so whatever you've set `Capybara.app_host` to would be where it connects.

Note: if you're using the racktest driver there is no support for connecting to remote apps at all, and any domain name specified is completely ignored.